# Kivy Android APK crashes when I flip the phone

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I am starting with Kivy and Android, trying to make an app, using also plyer to access the device sensors.

I am working with:

- Kivy: 1.9.1
- Buildozer: 0.32dev
- SO (desktop): Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- SO Android: Marshmallow 6.0

I took the following code from a web tutorial:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from plyer import accelerometer
from kivy.clock import Clock

class UI(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lblAcce = Label(text="Accelerometer: ") #create a label at the center
        self.add_widget(self.lblAcce) #add the label at the screen
        try:
            accelerometer.enable() #enable the accelerometer
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/24) #24 calls per second
        except:
            self.lblAcce.text = "Fallo al iniciar el acelerometro" #error

    def update(self, dt):
        txt = ""
        try:
            txt = "Aceleracion: \nX = %.2f\nY = %.2f\nZ = %2.f " %(
                accelerometer.acceleration[0], #read the X value
                accelerometer.acceleration[1], # Y
                accelerometer.acceleration[2]) # Z
        except:
            txt = "No se puede leer el acelerometro!" #error
        self.lblAcce.text = txt #add the correct text


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # display a button with the text : Hello QPython 
        usi = UI()
        return usi

if __name__== '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and build the APK with this buildozer.spec file (took off the commented blocks):

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Acelerometro 1

# (str) Package name
package.name = acc1

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy, plyer

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1
```

I forgot to set the

```
android.permissions
```

but had no problem about that. The problem is that when I turn down (flip) the phone (from portrait to landscape) the app crashes. I googled it, but couldn't find the answer. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Try setting `android.minapi = 13`

Comment: You should run `buildozer android run logcat` (or `buildozer android_new run logcat` if you're using the new toolchain) and post the relevant portion of the output from when your app crashes.

Comment: @jligeza it worked! thank you! You may want to take the SO point for yourself and that is what should be, so go ahead and post the answer if you want. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a bug, set `android.minapi = 13` or greater.